# How to address specific client/user using a message queue?

Tags: node.js, message-queue

I have developed an auction platform with node.js and socket.io.

However, I want to replace the socket.io with a message queue.

While I had no troubles in implementing the sockets based auction platform, I have no idea how to do this with a message queue.

The main thing I don't understand is how to address a specific client/user.

With socket.io I had the socket.id:

```
io.sockets.connected[socket.id].emit('notify', msg)
```

How does that work with a message queue like for example [Redis Simple Message Queue](https://github.com/smrchy/rsmq)?

I would be glad if someone could explain me how this works.

Comment: Assuming that the clients are going to be browsers, how are you going to access that message queue from the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket communication and Message Queues are not analogous. Socket.io provides continuous two-way communication between end points (client and server). A message queue provides a way to handle a sequence of items to be processed.

You haven't mentioned *why* you want to ditch your sockets and replace them with a message queue, but this is unlikely to work.

More likely, you could use a message queue *with* your socket connection, to pass a sequence of items to other parts of your system. Your socket connection would probably stay exactly as is, and when a message was received on the server, it would be placed into the queue, along with an identifier of the connection that sent it.